# Как лучше оптимизировать работу с БД MySQL для 500к записей?

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно как-то оптимизировать работу с БД. Собственно, как лучше это сделать?

**Исходные данные**

- Есть таблица в БД пусть `table`, в ней в записях есть числовые поля `point_id` и `not_found`. Остальные поля не важны.
- В памяти висит список порядка из 500 000 номеров (а точнее записей, в которых есть номер)

**Нужно организовать две операции**

1. В таблицу `table` добавить все записи из списка в памяти, но только тех, которых еще там нет - по полю `point_id`
2. В таблице `table` изменить поле `not_found` на 1 во всех записях, которые отсутствуют в списке висящем в памяти, по полю `point_id`

Смущает количество 500 000. Были бы десятки или сотни, можно было бы как-то поиграться с IN, NOT IN.

А в этом случае как правильно поступить?

Comment: Создать временную таблицу и список из памяти записать в неё. Далее `update ... join` двух таблиц. Примерно так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1439704/184217

Comment: Да, это то что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Для эффективной работы с БД в данном случае можно использовать транзакции и индексы.

1. Добавить новые записи из списка висящего в памяти можно с помощью оператора INSERT IGNORE. В этом случае, если запись уже есть в таблице, она не будет добавлена, а игнорирована. Также можно добавлять записи пакетами, чтобы уменьшить нагрузку на БД.
2. Чтобы изменить поле not_found на 1 в записях, которые не содержатся в списке в памяти, можно использовать оператор UPDATE с условием NOT IN, используя подзапрос с номерами записей из списка в памяти.

Также рекомендуется создать индекс на поле point_id в таблице table, чтобы ускорить поиск и снизить нагрузку на БД.

Примерный код для добавления новых записей из списка висящего в памяти:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (point_id, not_found)
SELECT point_id, 0 FROM memory_list
WHERE point_id NOT IN (SELECT point_id FROM table)
COMMIT;
```

Примерный код для изменения поля not_found на 1 в записях, которые не содержатся в списке в памяти:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE table SET not_found = 1 
WHERE point_id NOT IN (SELECT point_id FROM memory_list)
COMMIT;
```

Надеюсь, это поможет оптимизировать работу с БД.

Comment: INSERT IGNORE - то, что надо. А вот что за `memory_list`? Как туда 500 000 номеров добавить?

Answer (score 0):

Подходящий способ, думаю, сильно зависит от того, как много записей из тех которые 500К в памяти, нужно будет добавить.
Если новых записей меньше, например 50%, то лучше сравнение сделать в памяти.
Выбрать из базы упорядоченный массив (Recordset) table (point_id,not_found) и сравнить с массивом в памяти. Лучше если массив в памяти отсортирован по point_id. Тогда сравнение можно сделать за 1 проход, быстро. Добавлять только измененные и отсутствующие через UPDATE/INSERT по одной записи.

Чем меньше записей из памяти нужно добавить в таблицу, тем интересней будет сравнение в памяти, а не в СУБД.
Индекс по point_id поможет. Выборка `Select * from [table] order by point_id` будет быстрой.